# How to call django decorator only once per session?

Tags: python, django, session

**i want to call custom decorator only once per session**

```
def cust_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(request,*args, **kwargs):
       ........
       .......

wrapper.__doc__ = function.__doc__
wrapper.__name__ = function.__name__
return wrapper
```

i want to call **cust_decorator** decorator only once per session for a particular user

Comment: View decorators run every time the view is called, so they might not be the best way to get something to run once per session. You could store a flag in the session, check the flag in the decorator, and only run the code if the flag is not set.

Comment: there is no other way??

Comment: What are you actually trying to do by doing this?

Comment: i want show a alert only once per session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a session variable when the decorator has been called for the first time and check for this value to determine if the alert should be shown again. Another way could be to write your own middleware.